# Inserting Environment Variables into HTML files other than Index Using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, vue-cli

I've been developing a project built using the Vue CLI v3.*

I'm aware of how environment variables can be inserted into the `Index.html` file. But what about other html files?

Now that I am including oidc and silent refresh capability, I need to include a few more html files into the Public folder for the callbacks from the Identity Server e.g. `Silent-refresh.html`.

That file includes the url of the Identity Server in some of the `meta` elements, to satisfy CSP measures.

At the moment, when I swap between hitting my local Identity Server and a deployed one, I have to copy and paste the url into all places in the app.

It would be nice if I could just set it as an environmental variable, prefrexed with `VUE_APP` for use across the project, including such html files. Then I only have to change it in one place.

Is there a way to do this?
I believe some kind of webpack HTML plugin is involved, but I don't know how to configure it in such a way as to work with the Webpack plugin which is doing the same for the `Index.html` file.

The meta tags look like this:

```
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="frame-src <%= VUE_APP_IDPURL %>;"
    />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `pages` property in the `vue.config.js` `module.exports` to include the configuration for a different page than `index.html`.

You would have to include the configuration for your `index.html` file and the alternate page(s) as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the page
      entry: 'src/index/main.js',
      // the source template
      template: 'public/index.html',
      // output as dist/index.html
      filename: 'index.html',
      // when using title option,
      // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
      title: 'Index Page',
      // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
      // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    silentRefresh: {
      // you may use an empty noop js file because you only want to use the html template
      entry: 'src/index/silentRefresh.js',
      template: 'public/Silent-refresh.html',
      filename: 'Silent-refresh.html',
      title: 'Alternate Page'
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the reference to the docs on the [pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) property.

Comment: I'm still not quite there. It is still rendering the raw template text in the meta tags of the html page. Do I have to include anything else? References to lodash and or jquery?

Comment: Hmm could you include the meta tags of the html page?